# Finding Length with tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

I am trying to do this construction but I can't continue because I can't find the length a line segment CL

[image: [1]]

This is my code

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1]

    \tkzDefPoint(2,2){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(-2,2){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,4){D}
    \tkzDefPoint(4,2){E}
    \tkzDrawSegments[dashed](C,A D,B)

    % circumcircle
    \tkzCircumCenter(A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{O}
    \tkzDrawPoint(O)

    \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
    \tkzDrawCircle[dashed](D,O)

    \tkzInterCC[R](O,2 cm)(D,2 cm) \tkzGetPoints{M1}{M2}

    \tkzDrawCircle[dashed](B,M2)

    \tkzInterCC(O,A)(D,O) \tkzGetPoints{1}{2}
    \tkzInterLC(A,E)(B,M1) \tkzGetSecondPoint{M3}

    \tkzDrawCircle[dashed](M3,D)
    \tkzInterLC(O,C)(M3,D) \tkzGetSecondPoint{L}
    \tkzDrawSegments(C,L)

    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D,E,M1,M2,M3,O,L)

    \tkzDrawSegments(O,E)

    %\tkzDrawArc[delta=10,compass style/.append style={<->},thick](C,L)(D)

    \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,D,E,M1,M2,M3,O,L)

\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

But I need it looking something like, where D-P1 is the arc made by a compass, when extended to the length of the line segment D-P1

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `\tkzCalcLength(C,L)\tkzGetLength{dCL}`, then the length is stored in `\dCL`.